# Create "navigation breadcrumb"

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I am wondering how I am able to obtain this with CSS/CSS3 and HTML. How can this be done?

[image]

As you can see, I pointed out the 3 navigation breadcrumb.

Comment: You need a lot more information to get any helpful responses. Do you already have a mechanism for keeping track of the links the user has visited? If not, are you asking about that or are you simply asking how to style a breadcrumb display?

Comment: Just for display. Are there such "mechanism"? You know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        html{
            background:#222;
            font-size:12px;
            font-family:Arial;
        }

        ul#breadcrumbs{         
            list-style:none;
            /* optional */
            margin:100px;
            padding:10px 2px 10px 10px;
            background:#000;
            width:295px;
            height:30px;
            border-radius:5px;
            border:1px solid #222;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px 0 #000;
        }
        ul#breadcrumbs li{
            float:left;
            background:#93ce68 url(bg.png)no-repeat right;
            height:30px;
            padding:0 23px 0 10px;
            text-align:center;
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#000;
            line-height:32px;
        }
        ul#breadcrumbs li.active{
            background:url(bg.png)no-repeat right;
            color:#000;
        }
        ul#breadcrumbs li a{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#fff;
            line-height:32px;
            text-shadow:0 0 2px #222;
        }
        ul#breadcrumbs li a:hover{
            color:#a2ff00;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <ul id="breadcrumbs">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page2</a></li>
        <li class="active">About Us</li>
    </ul>



</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Save image in root of html and use clearfix for ul to clearing li float value. if you use CSS border technique, that may render blurry border in some browser.
Hope it will solve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed this myself... All i found was examples with lots of `::before` & `::after` pseudo elements. But I wanted to try out the new masking technic. Didn't find any, So I hacked together this myself:

**Note:** It's not the prettiest one that I have done, But it has the structural part needed to solve it using [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) It's experimental so don't count for this to work. I have only tested this in chrome

A awesome tool that helped me make this was [clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)
Just had to modify some points (x, y) to be mathematically calculated from the right side - the width of the arrow head `>`

```css
/* Make the hole background black (since it's hard to simulate a border around the arrow head)*/
#breadcrumb {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
}

#breadcrumb a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  margin-right: -17px;
}

/* Just to show that even around the arrow head, the mouse pointer is at the correct link */ 
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

/* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
#breadcrumb a:first-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="breadcrumb">
  <a href="#1">Home</a>
  <a href="#2">Contact</a>
  <a href="#3">Some extra long name</a>
  <a href="#4">Email</a>
</nav>
```